# Create collection from different tables in magento grid

Tags: grid

I am preparing a grid in which I need 7 fields and in this there will be  4 fields from table 1 2 fields from table 2 and 1 field from table 1.
I tried using concurrent left joints unfortunately did not succedd so please help.

```
$collection =Mage::getModel('name/name')->getCollection();    
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('table1', 'main_table.payment_id = payment_installment.payment_id',array('amount'));
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.order_id = sales_flat_address.entity_id',array('email'))
```

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Marius Please check I have  added code